# Angular 2, can i read the name of router-outlet of a component?

Tags: angular

i need to read the "name" of a router-outlet into a service. 
Example: a service get in input a reference from a component (with "this"), and this service need to know the name of router-outlet where the component is loaded.

html:

```
<router-outlet name="hello"><router-outlet>
```

component loaded in ruoter-outlet:

```
service_name.getComponet(this); // a reference of the component
```

in service:

```
public getComponent(comp: any) {
    compName = //?? how can i read the name "hello"? 
}
```

Comment: you can simply use the current active router name.. any specific reason for using this way

Comment: For example in a restored session, i need to distinguish every component. Anyway, i'm looking for a method to read the name in this way

Comment: you want the name of `router-outlet` or any other custom component?

Comment: Example: i have two instance of the same component, one loaded in <router-outlet name="abc"> and the second loaded in <router-outlet name="xyz">. If the first instance pass a reference of itself to the method getComponent in the service (so, the input is "this"), i want the service save "abc" in the variable compName

Comment: As mentioned, I'd add data to routes and read this data instead of reading from `<router-outlet>`.